# BULLSEYE unable to run chmod etc

Tags: pi-4, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

```
 $ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

Just installed BULLSEYE on a pi4 mod b

```
djb@bbbbbb:~ $ sudo chmod 775 /user/local/bin
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set
djb@bbbbbb:~ $
djb@bbbbbb:~ $ sudo chown djb:root /user/local/bin -R
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set
djb@bbbbbb:~ b
```

Also.  have tried to logon as "pi" and "root" --  password "raspberry" not valid!

Comment: Why on earth are you trying to change a system directory?

Comment: It sems like you have altered the permissions of some programs.  Easiest fix is to reinstall from scratch and not to change permissions until you understand what you are doing.

Comment: am adding my own bash files and also want to run the spt-get install

Comment: to double check what @joan indicated: what is the output of `ls -la /usr/bin/sudo`?

Comment: -rwxrwxr-x 1 djb root 176884 Feb 27  2021 /usr/bin/sudo

Comment: I will reinstall , again, expecting a different response. although I recall someone commented about expecting a different response in the past.

Comment: You changed the owner of `sudo` to user djb. it should be root which has uid 0 (zero)